# подключить к vue-form-wizard проверку vee-validate

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.6

Всем привет!

В laravel 5.6 / vue.js 2.5.7/ хочу подключить vue-form-wizard ( https://cristijora.github.io/vue-form-wizard/#/?id=call-a-function-before-tab-switch )
с использованием vee-validate либы. Непонятно как организовать валидацию при переходе на следующую закладку :

Я попытался вызвать метод validateDetailsTab которая должна вернуть true/false  в зависимости можно ли перейти на следующюю закладку
но всегда возвращется false из-за асинхронности вызова проверки :

```
<template>
    <section class="card col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8 offset-md-1 offset-lg-2">

        <div class="card-body">
            <form-wizard @on-complete="onComplete"
                         @on-loading="setLoading"
                         @on-validate="handleValidation"
                         @on-error="handleErrorMessage"
                         shape="tab" :color="wizard_color">

                <tab-content title="Details"  icon="fa fa-comment" :before-change="validateDetailsTab">
                    <div class="form-row mb-3">
                        <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-form-label" for="name">Name <span class="required"> * </span></label>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                            <input v-validate="'required|max:255'" v-model="userChat.name"
                                   :class="{ 'form-control':true, 'input': true, 'text-danger': vueErrorsList.has('name') }" name="name" id="name"
                                   type="text" placeholder="name">
                            <span v-show="vueErrorsList.has('name')" class="text-danger">{{ vueErrorsList.first('name') }}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    ...

                </tab-content>

                <tab-content title="Additional Info" icon="fa fa-tasks">
                    Task
                </tab-content>


            </form-wizard>
        </div>

    </section>
</template>



<script>
    import {bus} from '../../app';
    import appMixin from '../../appMixin';
    Vue.component('markdown-editor', require('../../components/lib/MarkdownEditor.vue'));

    import {FormWizard, TabContent} from 'vue-form-wizard'
    import 'vue-form-wizard/dist/vue-form-wizard.min.css'

    export default {
        components: {
            FormWizard,
            TabContent
        },

        data: function () {
            return {
                is_page_loaded: false,
                userChat: {
                    name: '',
                    description: '',
                    task_id: '',
                    status: '',
                    userChatParticipantsArray: [],
                },

            }
        }, // data: function () {

        mixins: [appMixin],

        created() {
        }, // created()

        mounted() {
            this.is_page_loaded = true
        }, // mounted() {

        computed: {
            header_title: function () {
                return "New user's chat";
            },
        }, // computed: {

        methods: {
            onComplete: function(){
                alert('Yay. Done!');
            },

            setLoading: function(value) {
                console.log(" setLoading value::")
                console.log( value )

                this.loadingWizard = value
            },

            handleValidation: function(isValid, tabIndex){
                console.log('handleValidation Tab: '+tabIndex+ ' valid: '+isValid)
            },

            handleErrorMessage: function(errorMsg){
                console.log("handleErrorMessage errorMsg::")
                console.log( errorMsg )

                this.errorMsg = errorMsg
            },



            validateDetailsTab:function() {
                var ret= false
                this.$validator.validateAll().then((result) => {
                    if (!result) {
                        bus.$emit('validateDetailsTab', 'create-user-chat-wizard', '');
                        this.showPopupMessage('Error in details data. ', 'error');
                        ret= false;
                        return;
                    }
                    ret= true;
                })

                console.log("ret::")
                console.log( ret )
                return ret;

            },

        } // methods: {

    }



</script>
```

А как правильно ?

Спасибо!

Comment: Какая ошибка в консоли?

Comment: В консоле ошибок нет. Непонятно, можно ли из validateDetailsTab вернуть результат валидация и если да то как ?